# Rebuilding old (2010) django project in 2012

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, sorl-thumbnail

I am trying to make an old Django project run again.

Update #1: I removed the arguments extra_thumbnails and size so the server is running. But now I don't have proper thumbnails of my pictures...

```
    image = ImageWithThumbnailsField(
    upload_to='images',
    thumbnail={'size': (120, 120)},
    extra_thumbnails={
        'icon': {'size': (32, 32), 'options': ['crop', 'upscale']},
        'large': {'size': (640, 640)},
    }
```

now looks only:

```
    image = ImageField(
    upload_to='images')
```

--

After seemingly having solved issues with old sorl.thumbnail versions and deprecated expressions I now get this error when running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I also tried to copy & paste my old files into a new Django project and get the exactly same error. Maybe someone here has a clue where the problem lies?

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x2a80510>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/me/Documents/wdws/wdws/../wdws/cityofwindows/models.py", line 73, in <module>
    class Image(models.Model):
  File "/home/me/Documents/wdws/wdws/../wdws/cityofwindows/models.py", line 83, in Image
    'large': {'size': (640, 640)},
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 233, in __init__
    super(FileField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_thumbnails'
```

I need to re-build the project just for visual documentation locally... so also any hints on how to quickly re-run outdated django-projects are very welcome!!

Thanks a lot!

(using Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess into the dark: Remove the keyword argument `extra_thumbnails` in the field definition `FileField` in the file `cityofwindows/models.py`

If this does not solve the problem, please post the cityofwindows/models.py file.

Comment: I realize that it must be sorl.thumbnail and the deprecated ImageWithThumbnailsField that I just changed to ImageField without having looked at the arguments... I guess I'll have to figure how to use ImageField then... thx!

Comment: If my answer pointed you in the right direction / solved your problem, please mark my answer, showing the rest of the community that your issue has been solved, and adds, as a nice side effect, some karma points to my profile ;-)

Comment: Thanks to you, indeed! But ImageField acts differently than ImageWithThumbnailsField, I had to remove extra_thumbnails + the size argument to make the server run but now my images do not have a thumbnail anymore... but this step total gratitude to you :)

Comment: sorl.thumbnail also has a different syntax for using thumbnails in the templates. Also, the configuration in settings.py is different.

Answer (score 0):

You probably uses another version of Django. Install Django 1.0 (https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.0.4/tarball/) is the easiest why, but not the best. You'd better update your project with the standards of the version 1.3 (see 1.4)